# Populate MVC form from typing into a textbox (returning data to form based on what's typed into the textbox)

Tags: javascript, c#, sql-server, model-view-controller

I have a textbox - You should be able to enter a phone number here.
Upon entering your number, the form should then populate the user.
If the number is incorrect or does not exist, it should do nothing.

Anyone have some code to this, I probably need javascript code and a mvc function in the controller to do this, but not sure how to. Or can you give a site with examples of a similar project please.

Comment: This question is not suitable for stackoverflow, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)